# Emulate Server-Client TCP Communication

Tags: server, wireshark, emulation, packets

I have a device (made in china) that works great but with a very annoying flaw. It's a massage device that will only work if it is connected to the internet at startup. Once it starts, it would work without the internet until it is turned off. So in short, if the internet is down, it will never work or it is impossible to bring this device on an area with no connection.

What I'm planning to do is emulate its server/client communication at start-up by using an old-PC that would run the server emulator software and some DNS re-routing and a WiFi router (using the PC as WAN).

I'll connect the device on the router, and its communication with the Chinese Server is emulated by the PC.

Can anyone give me an idea where to start, tools needed etc? I'm a programmer but new to packet emulation/replay. I've sniffed packets that the device does and its always consistent on every start/restart of the device. Here's the wireshark capture (IMG):

[WireShark Packet Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5DSS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two tasks, IMHO neither of them requires special tools:

### Redirect requests to local address

You need to setup local DNS server and configure it to provide local IP address on hengdetech lookup. I didn't dive into this part, but google has plenty of forums discussing necessary config for different DNS servers.

Device most likely gets DNS server address from DHCP server. So you need to point device to local DNS instead of default one by configure DHCP server (which is run on your router, I suppose).

Once your DHCP configures local DNS and local DNS redirects hedgdete to local IP address, you are free to go to the second part which is

### Emulate server behavior

Server must wait for some initial data from client before sending some data back. Such logic doesn't fit well into common "replay packets" tool capabilities, but it's quite easy to implement dumb TCP server with desired functionality on whatever language you like. Open socket, wait for data, send data, not a big deal, isn't it? So I wouldn't bother searching for the right tool, but would creat new instead.

If you need quick proof of concept, that you understand data flow right, before start coding, you may try netcat utility on Unix system for quick server emulation. I did the following once: extracted exchanged payload data from traces and saved as binaries (e.g. file1.bin is sent by server after the first request, file2.bin is sent after the second etc), then used something like this: `cat - file1.bin - file2.bin | nc -l -p <local_port> -n`. Using `cat` without dashes results into `nc` sending all files content to client, once it connects. Dash means "use data from console input rather than file" and they are used only as flow control. `cat` hangs on the first dash waiting for user input, so pressing `ctrl+d` proceeds to next file content and sends file1.bin, then hangs on the second dash. So you wait for the first request, press `ctrl+d` to send file1.bin content, then wait for the second request, press `ctrl+d` to send file2.bin content and so on.

### EDIT

You generally got the idea of extracting data from wireshark traces right, but I want to clarify some subtlenesses.

> When you said "saved binaries", did you mean to save individually captured packets as binaries so that netcat could send them to clients as a reply one by one (with the help of dash) ? If so, how do I save captured packets as binaries? Can I just extract them from the wireshark capture files, paste it on a new file and save as binary?

Only payload part of the packet needs to be saved, not the whole packet. TCP header, IP header and so on shouldn't be extracted, only tcp data section should be saved. Check second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743773/how-to-extract-raw-data-from-tcp-packets-using-wireshark/41352469#41352469) for howto. I suppose, TCP data in your case consists of binary data rather than plain text, so you need to copy it as "raw binary" and use some binary editor allowing to paste "raw binary" into file such as [frhed](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/). So yes, you create new file and paste data copied from wireshark into it, so file consists of exactly the same bytes as packet payload.

Another thing to mention, TCP is a stream protocol, one packet doesn't always mean one response message. If you see several TCP packets of maximum size (aka [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit), which is usually 1.5 Kbytes) without PSH flag followed by packet of lesser size with PSH flag, they all contain parts of the single response message, so their payloads should be combined into one "fileX.bin".

Comment: I can setup a DNS server on my mini box no problem (old PC). Regarding using netcat utility, when you said "saved binaries", did you mean to save individually captured packets as binaries so that netcat could send them to clients as a reply one by one (with the help of dash) ? If so, how do I save captured packets as binaries? Can I just extract them from the wireshark capture files, paste it on a new file and save as binary? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes I totally know about "just the payload" part of the packet. And yes I see on the captured packets about PSH flags, but they're in reverse of what you mentioned. First part have ACK with no PSH with 0 length, then the next stream is PSH ACK with length 4. I really don't know what to do with the 0 length stream since there is no payload to copy but it is in the communication sequence so maybe it matters.

I also found in wireshark based on the link you mentioned that I could save the payloads directly as binaries. Thanks!

Comment: You can ignore 0 length packets. They don't transfer data, but are used to maintain TCP functionality (e.g. acknowledge packet receiving). They will be generated by netcat automatically: netcat know how to build valid TCP session, it doesn't know which data to send.

Comment: Hi @nnovich. Finally I did some testing and its very promising. Since I decided to use windows for all the emulation and DNS spoofing. I used MaraDNS, and set my cheap wifi router to give the laptops IP as the DNS server and name resolution works! I verified it using wireshark.

Since I'm still out of town and I have no access to the massager, I did a reverse testing to see if packet replaying would work. I used netcatGUI (for windows) and connected to hengdetech.cn (I'm emulating the massage device). netcat connects and I can send the right packets but I get "FRAME CHECK SEQ" error.

Comment: Here is a wireshark capture of my reverse testing. I'm emulating the massage device to see if I could trick the chinese server to send me packets like it should with the actual massage device.
http://imgur.com/a/WAtKR <- as you can see I've sent the binary packets exactly as the actual chair does as seen on the screenshot on my original post.

Can you help me with the FRAME SEQUENCE INCORRECT error? Is this a proof that If I'll have access to the device next week and I emulate the server that I will get the same error? Thank you!

Comment: This looks more like wireshark parsing trouble rather than real error. Packet retransmission happened in the beginning of the session and then wireshark seems to be confused with it. Anyway, your packets are acknowledged by server, which is good. If server sent back expected data, everything must have worked fine.